# How to search on levelOrder values un SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server that contains the following columns :

```
Id  Name     ParentId  LevelOrder
8   vehicle  0         0/8/
9   car      8         0/8/9/
10  bike     8         0/8/10/
11  House    0         0/11/ 
...
```

This creates a tree.

Say that I have the LevelOrder `0/8/`, this should return only the car and bike rows, but how do I handle this in SQL Server?

I have tried :

```
Select * FROM MyTable WHERE LevelOrder >= '0/8/'
```

but that does not work.

Comment: Do you want only the immediate children (in which case use `where parentId = 8`), or all downstream nodes?  That is, would you want a mountainBike `(12, mountainBike, 10, 0/8/10/12)` returned?

Comment: What datatype is `LevelOrder` ?? String?

Comment: @X-Zero > Yes I want not only the immediate children but the downstream nodes also.

Comment: @marc_s  > Yes its a string(nchar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underscore character will guarantee at least one character comes after '0/8/', so you don't get a match on the "vehicle" row.

```
SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE LevelOrder LIKE '0/8/_%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This code allows you to select values that start with `0/8/`

```
Select * FROM MyTable WHERE LevelOrder like '0/8/%'
```

Comment: This would also match the "vehicle" row, which should not be included.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - 
While @Joe's answer is the simplest and easiest to implement (and possibly better performing than what I'm about to propose...), there are some issues with update anomalies.
Specifically:

1. You already have a `parentId` column.  You need to synchronize both this and  the `levelOrder` column, or risk inconsistent data.  (I believe this also violates 1NF, although my understanding of the exact definition is a little sketchy...)
2. `levelOrder` contains the entire heirarchy.  If any one parent is moved, all children rows must have `levelOrder` modified to reflect this (potentially very messy).

In light of this, here's what I recommend:

1. Drop the `levelOrder` column, as its existence will (generally) cause problems.
2. Use a recursive CTE and the `parentId` column to build the heirarchy dynamically.  Either leave the column where it is, or move it to a dedicated relationship table.  Moving one parent then requires only one cell to be updated, and cannot result in any (data, not semantic) anomalies.  The CTE should look similar to this form (will need to be adjusted for purpose):
   `WITH heir_parent (parentId, id) as (SELECT parentId, id
                                       FROM table
                                       WHERE id = 
                                       UNION ALL
                                       SELECT b.parentId, b.id
                                       FROM heir_parent as a
                                       JOIN table as b
                                       ON b.parentId = a.id)`

At the moment, the CTE returns a list of all children of the given id, with their id and their immediate parent.  It can be adjusted to return a number of other things as well - although I recommend that the CTE be used only to generate the relationship, and join externally to get the remaining data.